# Terminal command to find unique pairs where order does not matter

Tags: command-line, awk, terminal, filtering

I have a Python script `my_script.py` which generates a list of tab-separated pairings between two elements, one for each line:

```
$ python my_script.py
cat dog
dog wolf
cat dog
pig chicken
dog cat
```

I am looking to pipe the output of this script into a terminal command of some sort that I want to filter out duplicate *combinations*, not just duplicate permutations.  For duplicate permutations, I can use something like:

```
$ python my_script.py | sort | uniq
cat dog
dog cat
dog wolf
pig chicken
```

to remove the duplicate "cat dog".
The problem with this approach is that I am left with both "cat dog" and "dog cat", which for my purposes should be treated as the same (same combination).  I know I could write another very simple Python script to perform the kind of filtering I am after, but I wanted to see whether there is an even simpler terminal command that will do the equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
... | awk -F "\t" '!a[$1,$2]++ && !a[$2,$1]++'
```

Results:

```
cat dog
dog wolf
pig chicken
```

Explanation:

```
-F "\t"           # sets the field (column) separator to a single tab character

!a[$1,$2]++       # adds column one and column two to a pseudo-multidimensional
                  # array if they haven't already been added to the array

!a[$2,$1]++       # does the same thing, but adds the columns in the opposite
                  # orientation.
```

> Putting it altogether:
>
> So for every line of input, the line will be printed if and only if the first two fields (in either orientation) don't exist in the array. You can read more about how to emulate a multi-dimensional array [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multi_002ddimensional.html#Multi_002ddimensional).

Comment: Any chance of a brief description of what is actually going on here in the awk script for novice awk users like myself?

Comment: @BryceThomas: Added an explanation :-)  Please let me know if I haven't provided enough detail. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Caution: script above doesn't provide any output for cases where $1==$2 . Can test via:

```
echo "dog dog" | awk '!a[$1,$2]++ && !a[$2,$1]++'|wc -l
```

Try this instead:

```
|awk '{if($1<$2)print $1,$2; else print $2,$1}'|sort|uniq
```